# How to input current time in python

Tags: python, date, time

I need some help on datetime

here is my code:

```
import datetime
x = int(input()).datetime.datetime()
print(x.strftime("%B, %d, %Y"))
```

My custom input: 12 25 1990

but I always got an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12 25 1990'`
I just wanted the output to be " December 25, 1990" can anybody help thank you;;

Comment: Your input is `12 25 1990`. You're trying to convert this to an int using the int function.

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime()` to parse a time input.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar suggested, use datetime.strptime:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), '%m %d %Y')
print(x.strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
```

output (for input `12 25 1990`)

```
December 25, 1990
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options either prepare the `datetime` object by splitting the input and preparing date, month, etc. as:

```
import datetime
date_entry = '12 25 1990'
month, day, year = map(int, date_entry.split())
x = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print(x.strftime("%B, %d, %Y"))
```

---

Or simply use `strptime` to create the date from the input format as:

```
date_entry = '12 25 1990'
res = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_entry, '%m %d %Y')
print(res.strftime("%B, %d, %Y"))
```